# Как проверить адрес электронной почты на существование?

Tags: c#, email, mailkit

Моя программа отправляет код на почту пользователя для регистрации и авторизации, но если почты не существует, то сообщение отправляется в никуда. Могу ли я как-то проверить почту на существование? (может есть какие-то инструменты в mailkit или в system.net или для этого нужно использовать стороннее сервисы)

```
public void SendEmailAsync(string emailGetter, string subject, string message)
        {
            using var emailMessage = new MimeMessage();

            emailMessage.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("FitnessHelper", "login@yandex.ru"));
            emailMessage.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(emailGetter));
            emailMessage.Subject = subject;
            emailMessage.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = message
            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                try
                {

                    client.Connect("smtp.yandex.ru", 465, true);
                    client.Authenticate("login@yandex.ru", "password");
                    client.Send(emailMessage);


                    Console.WriteLine("The message was sent succesfully");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    stateOfmessage = false;
                }
                finally
                {
                    client.Disconnect(true);
                    client.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Если адресата не существует, то оно обычно возвращается с ошибкой.

Comment: ИМХО, не ваша головная боль. Если пользователь при регистрации ввел адрес, к которому у него нет доступа, и с которого он не получил код, то вам какая разница что он ввел? Ваша задача при регистрации, получить цифры, если они верны - сохранить почту, иначе, ничего не делать. Ну а так, делать кучу проверок, это может оказаться даже вредным в неком роде.

Comment: @ГеннадийП , в том то и дело что ни ошибки ни исключения нет

Comment: а что вы понимаете под "существованием почты"?

Comment: А что это за SmtpClient? Смотрю в System.Net.Mail - у этого класса нет методов Connect и Authenticate.

Comment: @rotabor , это из библиотеки классов MailKit. Её Майкрософт рекомендуют использовать вместо своих инструментов.

Comment: @JustOrex При отправке вам ошибку и исключение никто не выдаст, только в редких случаях когда письмо на локальный сервер отправляется, и то не всегда. Письмо отправляется как обычно, доходит до целевого сервера, сервер его возвращает обратно т.к. адресат не существует, и оно попадает вам в папку входящих. А так, полностью согласен, если пользователь ввел несуществующую почту, то ССЗБ.